# How can I make my plugin detect if a certain theme is active?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I made a WordPress plugin, so now what I want is, I want to set a logic like if a certain theme is active, then load the plugin. Else, only keep the plugin activated, but don't apply any changes on the site.
Any idea how can I achieve that? Sorry if I sound very nerdy :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_stylesheet()` to get the directory name of the theme being used. If a child theme is being used you can determine the parent with `get_template()`.

At the top of the plugin file you can simply `return` early if the value is not what you want.

```
if ( 'my-theme' !== get_stylesheet() ) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_get_theme()` function to get information about the active theme and specify its name.

```
add_action('init', 'pre_function_test');
function pre_function_test()
{
    $var = wp_get_theme();
    $theme_name = $var['Name'];
    if( $theme_name == 'Hello Elementor'){
       wp_die('is theme verify !');
    }
}
```

Here my theme name is Hello Elementor and my condition is executed.

**Note**: You can see the theme name from the theme directory and style.css file.

The wp_get_theme() function returns the current theme information.

See in this picture:

[image: get wordpress theme name]